# OpenIndiana Hipster GUI (Illumos): How do I ensure my installed pkgsrc packages are always the latest?

Tags: illumos, openindiana, pkgsrc

I run [OpenIndianaHipster GUI](http://docs.openindiana.org/handbook/getting-started/) and would like to ensure that my pkgsrc [packages](https://www.openindiana.org/packages/) are always the absolute latest available in the repos.

What is required to do this (it's not particularly clear to me from the [setup instructions](https://pkgsrc.joyent.com/install-on-illumos/))? Is simply running `# pkgin -y full-upgrade` sufficient, or do I *also* have to upgrade from the previous quarterly release pkgsrc trunk set every time a new pkgsrc trunk set quarterly release becomes available?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all you need to do is run `# pkgin -upgrade`.

Comment: I guess the `-` here is a mistake, a typo: https://pkgin.net/#:~:text=pkgin%20upgrade